# Java Class.cast to most specific with method overloading

Tags: java

I have a code that looks like this

```
function a(Object m) {} 
function a(BasicDbObject) {}
function a(TypeA) {}
function a(TypeB) {}
function a(TypeC) {}
.....
function b(Object m) {
    // Some function using Java reflection to determine class of Object m
    Class X = c(m); 
    a(X.cast(m));

}
```

Here is the problem. It always execute `a(Object m)` rather than `a(BasicDbObject m)`, even it is `BasicDbObject`.

My end goal is to execute most closest function to the object passed.

Comment: Try `a((BasicDbObject) m);` which should always call that method.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There are multiple method overloading. It can be either of dozen of classes.

Comment: Note: `BasicDbObject.class` is a `Class<BasicDbObject>` so `BasicDbObject.class.getClass()` is `Class<Class<BasicDbObject.class>>`

Comment: Your second attempt should be `a(BasicDbObject.class.cast(m))`. The one you tried retrieves the `Class` object representing the type `Class` itself.

Comment: Note: The binding is determined at compile time so `a(clazz.cast(m))` will always bind to `a(Object)` as this is the only type known at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> function a(Object m) {}
>   function a(BasicDbObject) {}

When methods are *overloaded*, it may not be intuitive to know the method which gets invoked for any set of parameters because, unlike the situation with *overridden* methods, the method overloading that gets invoked is determined at compile time (i.e. statically) rather than at run time (i.e. dynamically).  This behavior is confusing because overriding methods is more common and this sets our expectations for method invocation.

There are some rules for doing method overloading as robustly and as simply as possible.  These are all nicely enumerated in Effective Java (J. Bloch, 2nd and 3rd eds.).

Your situation is made complex because:

- You have two overloadings with the same number of parameters whose types are not **radically different** ... and ...
- The behavior of the overloadings is apparently dependent on the type of the parameter (if the behavior was identical, then you simply have one overloading forward to the other)

When this situation arises, you should try to correct it by giving the overloadings different names.  It should always be possible to do this and doing so often improves the clarity and maintainability of the code.

If this can't be done for any reason, then the best workaround is to replace the overloadings with a method that accepts the most general parameter type and which invokes helper methods based on the most specific type of the passed argument.

So instead of the above, you can get the behavior you want by using...

```
public Function a(Object m) {

    if (m instanceof BasicDbObject) return doDbObject(m);
    if (m instanceof OtherDbObject) return doOtherDbObject(m);

    return doGenericObject(m);
}
```

Note that this isn't the code that you would use when Java adopts pattern matching in the language.  Note also that the effect of this code is to give your overloadings different names, but the selection of the distinct method is made at run time using `instanceof` comparisons rather than at compile time by simply using a distinct name.

TLDR; if you are doing method overloading in a circumstance in which the parameter types are not (or may not be) **radically different** then you are better off not overloading and using distinct method names.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying cannot be done, because Java is statically typed, and the method overload is resolved at compile-time, not run-time.

The only way to resolve the overload at runtime, is for the method call itself to be done with reflection.

Comment: I am trying to use reflection for this purpose, but I seem to be failing somehow

Comment: @VarunAgrawal Because you're using `cast()` with a hardcoded method call. You need to use [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), so you can dynamically choose *which* method to [`invoke()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-), at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Serious non-answer: wrong approach.

You don't use *reflection* to dynamically determine a type, to then figure which overloaded method to call.

Instead, use polymorphism. Meaning: don't **overload**, but **override**.

Rest assured: getting "reflection" *working* is hard. Getting it **correct**, and **robust** and **stable** is a super challenging, uphill battle.

You basically want to invent your own personal dynamic dispatch implementation. Unless you have super hard pressing reasons to do so, that is a terrible idea. Because chances are that you will get it wrong. Many many times. And even when your code is working, there will be many incidents later on, when unforeseen things happen in production.

As said: don't do this. Don't fight the language, instead use the means that the language offers you to solve such problems: an inheritance tree of classes, and polymorphic methods. Then let the JVM decide which method to invoke. Most likely, the JVM will do a much better job, compared to what you will come up with.

Comment: I have no idea how to polymorphism is this case. There are like 20 function each for a different data type. The only solution other than reflection I know is, to use 20 if-else conditions, with manual typecasting (basically other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640852/2286243)

Comment: *"I have no idea how to polymorphism is this case. There are like 20 function each for a different data type. "* ... No?  The boxed data types `Double`, `Long`, and `Integer` are all distinct types, but they are all subtypes of the abstract class `Number`.  The `Number` class defines abstract methods that each of the subclasses must implement.  Can you begin to see how overriding methods will provide you with a much better, much more robust solution to your problem than method overloading will?

Comment: +1 agree with the basic idea that "if your first inclination toward solving many problems is to do reflection, then you're probably doing it wrong."